# Current RAM size not calculated correctly | Graphic card (and settings) not show in BIOS (BIOS 5, MSI X399)

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, bios, dram

I recently built up my own desktop PC for Deep Learning purposes. There are a few issues I'm not sure about, and I don't know if they are somehow related due to a defect, wrong hardware compatibility, bugs, etc. so I've combined them all in this post. I originally had Ubuntu 19.0 but then switched to Windows 10 because it seemed the installation of the CUDA, CUDnn stack is far easier on a Windows platform. My specs:

- AMD Threadripper 1920X
- EVGA RTX2080Ti XC Ultra
- MSI X399 SLI Plus
- Corsair Hydro H100i Pro
- 64GB 4x16Corsair Ven.
- Samsung SSD 970 EVO Series NVMe 1TB
- Thermaltake PC-Netzteil 1050W

***Issue #1***

The "Current DRAM Size" does not show the correct total size from the collective RAMs (4 * 16GB CORSAIR VEN. - please see pictures from the BIOS and Windows 10).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have an MSI X399 SLI Plus motherboard (BIOS 5). Despite the RAM modules being recognised for all for slots - and thus IMO eliminating any problems related to poorly slotted RAMs, faulty RAMs etc. - the total is still appearing to "miss" one (so instead of 64GiB, only 48GiB is calculated/shown). I'm not 100% certain, but in my initial boot with Ubuntu, I think I had in the OS level 64GB RAM. I've also used this [troubleshooting guide](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-isnt-using-all-ram/).

Admittedly I haven't gone through every single possibility in this link, I still would need to try out updating the BIOS (which is a bit of a last resort). Also some of the options do not appear in the BIOS that is recommended in Section 6, which leads me on to Issue 2...

***Issue #2***

The graphics card is shown in Windows 10 Control panel/system (though I still need to confirm whether the graphic card is being utilised properly for my deep learning python scripts), however it is not showing up in my BIOS. Consequently I am unable to try out the settings in Section  of this [link](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-isnt-using-all-ram/).

Comment: One question only per post, please.

Comment: Your ram is quad channel?

Comment: @DarkBeccio yes, 4 channels out of a possible 8 slots (DIMMA2, DIMMB2, DIMC2, DIMMD2)

Comment: Time can be stored in UTC in nvram (aka EUFI settings) or as local time. If windows and firmware diagree,then you get those time issues. I think this was answered before somewhere on the site (it should be since it is not uncommon). So best to separate that part from the question.

Comment: @Hennes I updated the question by omitting the time question, I left the 2 other issues in because they could be related somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the RAM issue. Actually it was a stupid mistake on my behalf, but I think it could be too easily overlooked:

Basically, for the MSI X399 motherboard, when you slot the RAM sticks into place, the corresponding LED for that slot is then triggered on the motherboard (and thus it is "recognised"). After trying numerous BIOS/Windows10 settings, I went back to just checking the RAM sticks. I noticed when I put the last stick (so I think "D") into place after taking it out, I almost assumed it was back into place as it "clicked", but then I realised the bottom part of the stick was not slotted into place properly. After then rebooting and going into the BIOS, the 64GB was again present.